# Python finding paths of trees using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, tree, return, path-finding

I've been trying to implement an Huffman encoding algorithm based on numeric digits. I've done the part to construct an Huffman tree. But the recursion algorithm doesn't work as expected. It should return the paths in the tree from the root to the designated node, but it always return the wrong path.

The strange thing is, the code seems to be doing what is correct, and it can find the real path. But the result it returns is always something else.

```
def get_encoding_for(symbol_p, node, encoding):
    global encoded_string
    result = encoding
    if not isinstance(node, list):
        if symbol_p == node:
            encoded_string = result
            return result
    else:
        for n in node:
            index = str(node.index(n))
            # print("Node {} with index {}".format(n, index))
            result = get_encoding_for(symbol_p, n, encoding + index)

    return result
```

The tree is structured using simply lists.

```
The huffman tree looks like: [[3.0, [1.0, 2.0]], [4.0, 5.0]]
```

This is an example output of a simple tree using elements 1,2,3,4,5.

```
Loop 1.0. Node 1.0 -> Coding 010:
Loop 2.0. Node 2.0 -> Coding 011:
Loop 3.0. Node 3.0 -> Coding 00:
Loop 4.0. Node 4.0 -> Coding 10:
Loop 5.0. Node 5.0 -> Coding 11:
```

This is what I want the function to return, but it only returns me "11" in all the five iterations. I had to use a global variable to "intercept" the correct coding and I'm not happy with this... I think the problem is on the returning. I've tried a lot of ways of returning but none of them worked.

Can someone tells me what's wrong about the recursion? Thank you so much!

Comment: The problem is that your recursion doesn't end when it finds the correct path, it just keeps going until it's traversed every single path in the tree. That's why the return value is always `11` - that's the final path in your tree. You need to add a mechanism to detect if you've found the element you're searching for, and stop the `for n in node:` loop.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but why won't the "return result" stop the method?

Comment: There's no `return` in your `for` loop. The `return` happens _after_ the loop, so you get the _last_ value, not the correct one.

Comment: If there's a `return` in the `for` loop, it would stop too early and won't be able to find the path... Each node can have as many sub-nodes.

Comment: That's why I'm saying you need a mechanism that allows you to stop at exactly the right time...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your given code into a text file and reproduce the problem.
Your current code has syntax errors (indentation), there's no call to the function, and there's no line capable of producing the output you cite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different approach (from those in my first answer) is to separate generating paths from the stopping logic.

```
def paths(bintree):
    if isinstance(bintree, list):
        for i, p in ((0,'0'), (1,'1')):
            for val, path in paths(bintree[i]):
                yield (val, p + path)
    else:
        yield (bintree, '')

def encoding2(i, bintree):
    for val, path in paths(hufftree):
        if i == val:
            return path
    return ''

# Test
hufftree = [[3, [1, 2]], [4, 5]]
for v in paths(hufftree): print(v)
for i in range(6):
    print(encoding2(i, hufftree))
# Prints

010
011
00
10
11
```

At this point, one might considered creating a dict mapping values to encodings.

```
huffdict = dict(paths(hufftree))
for i in range(6):
    print(huffdict.get(i, ''))
# Prints same as above
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching a tree for one item is a bit tricky.  Done recursively, the return needs to signal success (return again) or failure (recurse again).  Done iteratively, return is easy, but an explicit stack of possible search locations is needed.  The following does the former, taking advantage of the binary structure of the tree.  Note 1: I used names that made it easier for *me* to write this correctly.  They are not necessarily 'better'.  Note 2: I added a 'not found' case to the test.

```
def encoding(char, bintree, path):
    if isinstance(bintree, list):
        p = encoding(char, bintree[0], path+'0')
        if p:
            return p
        return encoding(char, bintree[1], path+'1')
    else:
        return path if char == bintree else ''

# Test
hufftree = [[3, [1, 2]], [4, 5]]
for i in range(6):
    print(encoding(i, hufftree, ''))
# Prints

010
011
00
10
11
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yeah the solution makes sense. I wonder how can it be extended for ternary, 4-nary trees?. The loop and return is killing me...